# Julia array of empty arrays

Tags: arrays, julia, empty-list

sorry for stupid simple question, newbie with Julia:

I would like to initialize array like this:

`folds = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`, but not manually.

In Python I just write

`folds = [[]] * 8`, but this is not working with Julia.

How this is possible with Julia? I tried several times, but now success.
Can you also explain to solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be a list comprehension (although this of course isn't quite as concise as Python):

```
[[] for i=1:8]
```

Comment: Note that this does not the same as the python version. `folds[i].append(x)` will append to all arrays in python, while in Julia the arrays will be independent.

Comment: @tim - very useful comment!

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of `folds = [[]] * 8` (which is probably not what you want!) in Julia is

```
folds = fill([], 8)
```

See the result of

```
push!(folds[1], 1)
8-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}:
 Any[1]
 Any[1]
 Any[1]
 Any[1]
 Any[1]
 Any[1]
 Any[1]
 Any[1]
```

and

```
folds[1].append(1)
# [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

On the other hand, a comprehension like `[[] for i = 1:8]` will create independent arrays in Julia and similar in python.

Comment: this does not work well with push!
push!(folds[1],1) will push 1 to every array

Comment: Yes, that's what I have shown in the result and what will happen for `[[]] * 8` in python as well. Its a common gotcha in python.

Comment: Yes, this answer more closely matches Python.